# I seem to have Firefox by way of Snap and normal install

Tags: software-installation, firefox, snap

Firefox is my main browser, and runs without any issues. It has one icon and no oddities. But when I update, I see it twice.

`sudo apt upgrade` included

```
Get:11 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [672 kB]                                                                                 
Get:12 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-eo amd64 84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [453 kB]                                                                                 
Get:13 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-fr amd64 84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [474 kB]                                                                                 
Get:14 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-ga amd64 84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [396 kB]
```

And then later,

```
Preparing to unpack .../09-firefox_84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-firefox-locale-en_84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-en (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-firefox-locale-eo_84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-eo (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-firefox-locale-fr_84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-fr (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-firefox-locale-ga_84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-ga (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (83.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ..
```

So I have Firefox installed as a normal package, right?

And yet, moments later, `sudo snap refresh` produced

```
2020-12-23T18:03:13Z INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
core 16-2.48 from Canonical✓ refreshed
firefox 84.0.1-1 from Mozilla✓ refreshed
core18 20201210 from Canonical✓ refreshed
postman 7.36.1 from Postman, Inc. (postman-inc✓) refreshed
chromium 87.0.4280.88 from Canonical✓ refreshed
```

Why do I *also* have Firefox installed as a snap package? Am I using that? (Firefox prompted me to restart it before I installed the snap version, so it appears that this isn't the one I'm using.) Or are the two installs related, and I need both? Or what?

Comment: You certainly don't need two. Mine runs perfectly without a snap.

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2020:

- The Firefox **snap** is not part of any default set of packages or snaps
- The Firefox **deb** is included with default set of applications for most *buntu desktops.

Neither the deb or the snap require the other. They are independent, and both can use the same profile and cache in your /home directory. Both receive frequent security upgrades from the Ubuntu Desktops and Ubuntu Security Teams.

You can safely leave both on your system. You can safely uninstall either one. Or both. Or alternate weekly, if you really want to.

---

**Warning**: Since many Desktop metapackages depend on Firefox, removing the Firefox **deb** may cause apt to also remove the `*buntu-desktop` package (or equivalent). **For most users, this does not cause any problems**.

For those rare, intrepid users who built their desktop from a Minimal installation (not the usual Desktop installer), removal of the `*-desktop` metapackage may make their desktop software stack eligible for (unexpected) autoremoval.

Since apt cannot understand or manipulate snaps, apt won't be affected at all by the install/removal of the Firefox **snap**.

Comment: I have no idea where I got the snap version from. I certainly have no memory of installing it. I must have done something at some point. I'll probably get rid of it, as this machine is low on space.